# How can I show an icon in the panel if (and while) a certain process is running?

Tags: unity, scripts, xubuntu, indicator, panel

I have a script that works in the background. I would like to show an icon in the panel (only) if it runs; it should not show if the script is not running, just like the Dropbox icon.

How can I achieve this?  I have installed `Xubuntu 14.04`.

Comment: What is the application? The icon should *change* or *appear*?

Comment: @JacobVlijm  

It is a script. When it is working an icon has to appear on the notification panel, and when it is not working it has to dissapear. The idea is to have a quick look and know if it is running or not.

Comment: btw, if you need other colors or would like to set anything from he indicator, just mention :)

Comment: Thank you Jacob. One question: is it possible to move the icon to another place? I mean, now it is in the middle of the "Indicator plugin". Can I move it to the beginning of the panel?

Comment: There are several ways to do that. The easiest trick is to change the category in the line `AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)` into `AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.SYSTEM_SERVICES)` or `AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.APPLICATION_STATUS)`. If neither delivers what you like there are other ways. Let me know.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Other ways?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, but in xfce, right-click on the indicator > panel > panel preferences > items > here you can make a number of alterations (double click the item, press up or down button)

Comment: Not exactly. This botton is inserted in "Indicator Plugin" and when I move this botton, all the bottons are moved with it. I would like to move it at the beginning of this group of bottons. Any ideas?

Comment: Looked around a lot, it seems the indicator plugin does not give any option(s) to set the order. What I also tried it adding two plugins, each with different settings. Partially works, but you get the network icon unavoidably duplicated. Bottom line is: no, you cannot set the order in xfce.

Comment: I did something like you explained (with two duplicated icons) but it is not exactly what I want. Thank you. Your information has been of great help for me.

Comment: @jos To avoid the duplicated icons, you could just use Jacob's solution for Unity and mine for Xfce. This would solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How to show an icon in the panel if a process runs

Based on (and explained in) [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/756519/72216), we can fairly easily create an indicator, which runs on both `Xubuntu` and Unity or any other flavour, to show if a process, a script or an application runs or not.

*script runs:*

[image]

*script doesn't run:*

[image]

In the script (indicator) below, I added a thread to detect the process to the indicator:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
from threading import Thread

# --- set the path to the script below
script = "/path/to/script.sh"
#---

currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def runs(script):
    # function to check if the process runs
    try:
        return subprocess.check_output(["pgrep", "-f", script]).decode("utf-8")
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        pass

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'show_proc'
        iconpath = currpath+"/nocolor.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())

        self.update = Thread(target=self.check_runs)
        # daemonize the thread to make the indicator stopable
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()     

    def check_runs(self):
        # the function (thread), checking for the process to run
        runs1 = ""
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            runs2 = runs(script)
            # if there is a change in state, update the icon
            if runs1 != runs2:
                if runs2:
                    # set the icon to show
                    GObject.idle_add(
                        self.indicator.set_icon,
                        currpath+"/green.png",
                        priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                        )
                else:
                    # set the icon to hide
                    GObject.idle_add(
                        self.indicator.set_icon,
                        currpath+"/nocolor.png",
                        priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                        )
            runs1 = runs2


    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)
        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script below into an empty file, save it as `show_proc.py`
2. In the head section of the script, in the line:

   ```
   # --- set the path to the script below
   script = "/path/to/script.sh"
   #---
   ```

   set the path to your script or applications
3. Copy both icons below (right click -> save as), and save them ***in one and the same directory as `show_proc.py`, and exactly named as indicated below***

   `green.png`

   [image]

   `nocolor.png`

   [image]  <-- this is a transparent icon, but is is there :). move the cursor over it until the finger appears...
4. Now test- run `show_proc.py` by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/show_proc.py
   ```

   and start up your script
5. If all works fine, add the following to sgtartup applications:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/show_proc.py"
   ```

Answer (score 2):

In Xubuntu, install the Generic Monitor panel plugin by pasting the following in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-genmon-plugin
```

From the [Generic Monitor plugin](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-genmon-plugin) page:
"This plugin cyclically spawns the indicated script/program, captures its output (stdout) and displays the resulting string into the panel.
The string can also contain markup to display an image, a bar, a button and a personalized tooltip."

Set the following script to run using the Generic Monitor panel plugin. I recommend without a Label. Be sure to replace `your_script` with the name of your script and add in the path to your icon.

```
#!/bin/bash

status=$(pgrep your_script)

if [ -n "$status" ]; then
    echo "<img>/path/to/your/icon.png</img>"
else
    echo ""
fi
```

It is interesting that you mention Dropbox. [I use this plugin for Dropbox.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/732967/dropbox-icon-is-not-working-xubuntu-14-04-lts-64#736727)

There are also [plugins for the panel in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102631/displaying-output-of-arbitrary-command-on-unity-panel/489450) that show command or script output. However, I just have Xfce so I can't confirm a particular one. I hope all works out great.