# How can I quickly disable standby lid off in Ubuntu Unity 16.04?

Tags: software-recommendation, suspend, power-management

What is the quickest way to quickly disable the standby feature when closing the lid? I very much like this behaviour but especially when playing music, I would like to close my lid without switching my machine into standby.

However, I do not want to permanently disable this feature but just temporarily turn it off until I finished listening to music, for example.

Maybe there is an indicator similar to [Caffeine](http://launchpad.net/caffeine)?

[image]

Comment: Are your settings similar for ac and battery?

Comment: There's  no such indicator yet.  There are ways,  but they require  root access  with `sudo` as shown in this post.   http://askubuntu.com/q/15520/295286. I'll see what can be done though

Comment: May I ask,  what kind of system version you are using?  16.04

Comment: Dear Jacob and Serg, thanks for the first comments and solutions! Jacob's script works great. It would be fantastic if this was a small indicator though. I just like visual GUIs. :-) Settings are similar for ac and battery. I edited my question to make clear that I am using Unity 16.04.

Comment: Can/will be done. GUI however will take a bit longer.

Comment: My deepest respect for your great work, Jacob!

Comment: Hi orschiro, done :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The script below will *toggle* the close-lid action between "nothing" and "suspend":

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

key = ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power",
       "lid-close-ac-action", "lid-close-battery-action"]

currstate = subprocess.check_output(["gsettings", "get",
    key[0], key[1]]).decode("utf-8").strip()

if currstate == "'suspend'":
    command = "'nothing'"
    subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Lid closes with no action"])
else:
    command = "'suspend'"
    subprocess.Popen(["notify-send", "Suspend will be activated when lid closes"])

for k in [key[1], key[2]]:
    subprocess.Popen(["gsettings", "set", key[0], k, command])
```

...And notify what is the currently set state:

[image]

#### How to use

Simply:

- Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `toggle_lid.py`
- Add it to a shortcut key: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

  ```
  python3 /path/to/toggle_lid.py
  ```

#### Explanation

The current state of the close-lid action setting can be retrieved by the command(s)

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action
```

(on power), and

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-battery-action
```

(on battery)

The script reads the current state, and sets the opposite ('suspend'/'nothing') with the command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power lid-close-ac-action '<action>'
```

---

### Optionally (additionally)

Optionally/additionally, you can run an indicator as a detector to show what is the current state of the lid- setting. It will show:

[image]

...in the panel, if the suspend will be prevented on closing the lid, It will show a grey one if not.

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import time
import signal
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
gi.require_version('AppIndicator3', '0.1')
from gi.repository import Gtk, AppIndicator3, GObject
from threading import Thread

key = ["org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power",
       "lid-close-ac-action", "lid-close-battery-action"]

currpath = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

def runs():
    # The test True/False
    return subprocess.check_output([
        "gsettings", "get", key[0], key[1]
        ]).decode("utf-8").strip() == "'suspend'"

class Indicator():
    def __init__(self):
        self.app = 'show_proc'
        iconpath = currpath+"/nocolor.png"
        self.indicator = AppIndicator3.Indicator.new(
            self.app, iconpath,
            AppIndicator3.IndicatorCategory.OTHER)
        self.indicator.set_status(AppIndicator3.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)       
        self.indicator.set_menu(self.create_menu())
        self.update = Thread(target=self.check_runs)
        # daemonize the thread to make the indicator stopable
        self.update.setDaemon(True)
        self.update.start()     

    def check_runs(self):
        # the function (thread), checking for the process to run
        runs1 = None
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
            runs2 = runs()
            # if there is a change in state, update the icon
            if runs1 != runs2:
                if runs2:
                    # set the icon to show
                    GObject.idle_add(
                        self.indicator.set_icon,
                        currpath+"/nocolor.png",
                        priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                        )
                else:
                    # set the icon to hide
                    GObject.idle_add(
                        self.indicator.set_icon,
                        currpath+"/green.png",
                        priority=GObject.PRIORITY_DEFAULT
                        )
            runs1 = runs2

    def create_menu(self):
        menu = Gtk.Menu()
        # quit
        item_quit = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
        item_quit.connect('activate', self.stop)
        menu.append(item_quit)
        menu.show_all()
        return menu

    def stop(self, source):
        Gtk.main_quit()

Indicator()
GObject.threads_init()
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_DFL)
Gtk.main()
```

#### How to use

1. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `show_state.py`
2. Copy both icons below (right click -> save as), and save them ***in one and the same directory as `show_proc.py`, and exactly named as indicated below***

   `green.png`

   [image]

   `nocolor.png`

   [image]
3. Now test- run `show_state.py` by the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/show_state.py
   ```

   and change the current state by pressing the shortcut you set the first section of this answer.
4. If all works fine, add the following to startup applications:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "sleep 15 && python3 /path/to/show_state.py"
   ```

#### Note

The detector- indicator above is an edited version of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/757599/72216). Simply by changing the test in the function `runs()` (and optionally the according panel icons), you can use it to show the state of *anything* that is `True` or `False`.

Comment: Excellent solution with the indicator! One question: Why did you decide for a [transparent icon](http://i.imgur.com/OAutzQz.png)?

Comment: @orschiro I consider(ed) the ste where the lid- closing will suspend as the *default* situation. The green one as an indication you *can* close the lid without action(s). It coul be any icon however. Suggestions?

Comment: Maybe like the green one but in fading-grey? It's slightly irritating to see an empty space in the indicator bar due to the transparency of the icon.

Comment: @orschiro haha, now I see what you mean :). edited.

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be changing from "Suspend" to "Do Nothing" in Ubuntu Settings - Power:

[image: Ubuntu Settings - Power]

PS: This doesn't provide an indicator in the notifications area but is simpler than creating a script for new users.

PPS: In this screen snapshot the UPS is for Cable Modem + Sony Android TV, not the laptop which has battery... HAHA.

Comment: Eh, Ok. Manual way, takes a few clicks here and there. But fairly decent.

Comment: @Serg I actually like the script posted by Jacob. Will probably play with it some day after I make Ubuntu 16.04 / Kernel 4.7.2 more stable on my system. Indeed my suspend on lid close never even worked out of the 14.04 to 16.04 upgrade box... had to setup a parameter in systemd which assumes when lid is closed you want TV to stay active and simply want to dim laptop screen . In hind sight I should have posted instructions for that too!

Comment: Yeah,  before 16.04 those options  didn't  really  work for me.  I personally  wanted to post the file editing as answer,  but Jacob has beaten me to it :)

Comment: In Unity 22.04 the Power settings has almost nothing compared to that screenshot!

Comment: @Déjàvu The answer was written in 2016, so Ubuntu 16.04 is the version.