# How to make a nautilus script written in python to run in terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, python, nautilus

I have written a code in python language that usage `subprocess.call()` method and `print` method, i am using this code as nautilus script and it is working fine. but there is no way to know that script is working right now, i can see the effect only after script completed.

I want this script to run in terminal so that i can know that script is running and there is a `print` method in the code that need to be print text when script fail but it does not shows up.

If there is other method than terminal please tell me.

Comment: Well, you could raise a terminal window from script and print stuff there. You could also display a  small popup with `zenity` that shows the script is working. One can also write a "progress" popup, either with `zenity` or  in Python via Gtk API, but that's overly complex for  a nautilus script I'd say.

Comment: Sometimes script output to the terminal ends up in `/var/log/syslog` when run in GUI. However @SergiyKolodyazhnyy hasn't pointed out to me before this isn't always the case.

Comment: This is probably totally overdoing things, but https://askubuntu.com/a/757599/72216. Used it to notice if and when my rsync backup was running :). Just to mention.

Answer (score 0):

Here is small snippet in bash, you can easy rewrite in python, it notify user trying to find a possible way:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

have_command() {
  type -p "$1" >/dev/null
}

try() {
  have_command "$1" && "$@"
}

in_terminal() {
  [ -t 0 ]
}

notify_user() {
  local msg="${2:-Error}: $1"
  echo "$msg" >&2
  in_terminal && return
  try notify-send "$msg" && return
  try yad --info --text="$msg" && return
  try zenity --info --text="$msg" && return
  try xmessage -buttons Ok:0 -nearmouse "$msg" -timeout 10 && return
  return
}
```

Install notify-send and you'll get nice messages